# raise ValueError("Cannot use None as a query value") ValueError: Cannot use None as a query value

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

views.py

```
def search_available_rooms(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        check_in_date = request.GET.get('check_in_date') 
        check_out_date = request.GET.get('check_out_date')
    
        if check_in_date and check_out_date:
            overlapping_bookings = Booking.objects.filter(start_date__lte=check_out_date, end_date__gte=check_in_date) 
            booked_rooms = [booking.room for booking in overlapping_bookings] 
            available_rooms = Room.objects.exclude(id__in=[room.id for room in booked_rooms]) 
        
            context = { 
                'available_rooms': available_rooms,
                'check_in_date': check_in_date,
                'check_out_date': check_out_date
            }
            return render(request, 'cat_hotel/cat_hotels.html', context=context)
        else:
            # Handle the case where one or both dates are missing
            return render(request, 'cat_hotel/cat_hotels.html', context={})
```

urls.py

```
path('cat_hotels/', views.search_available_rooms, name='search_available_rooms'),
```

> raise ValueError("Cannot use None as a query value") ValueError: Cannot use None as a query value

How do I solve this?

Comment: check if booked_rooms is empty

Comment: provide more information In which line of code the error appears?

Comment: Note, what you are trying to implement by hand-made iterations is a [Not Exists](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#filtering-on-a-subquery-or-exists-expressions) filter. You don't need to fetch bookings to send their room_id back to the database to filter Rooms. All of it can happen at once on DB side within a single query. Use [OuterRef](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) technique to link Bookings to their rooms when implementing `~Exists` predicate.